# How do I add some info in between a loop?

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

```
$data = explode(",", $str);
$names = array();
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($data); $i+=3) {  
    $names[] = $data[$i];
}
```

Suppose this gives the result:

```
mathews,neil,ambrose,glen,ethan
```

I want add `and` just before `ambrose` so the final result is:

```
mathews,neil, and ambrose
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid loops for this kind of operation, they add an unnecessary level of complexity to your code.

```
// put the last element of $data to $lastName, and remove the last element from $data
$lastName = array_pop($names);
echo join(',',$names) . ' and ' . $lastName;
```

There are also many one line variations like this:

```
// replace the last ",name" with " and name"
echo preg_replace('/(,)[a-z]+$/', ' and ', join(',', $names));
```

But they wouldn't be very clear to inexperienced PHP developers.

**edit**, If you are happy to ditch the array you already have in your example, you can do this.

```
$str = "mathews,neil,ambrose,glen,ethan";
$names = array_slice(explode(',', $str), 0, 3);
$lastName = array_pop($names);
echo join(',', $names) . ' and ' . $lastName;
```

Comment: I agree but here I want first three names. add and after second name..in that case how I do this without loop??

Comment: If you keep the loop you already have there it will give you the 3 names you want. Then use either of the above examples on the resulting $names array.

Comment: if you're happy to ditch the code you've already supplied, you can do my last example.

Comment: yeah man wow ..how do you learn all these?? which is the best method to learn PHP?? how I need to learn well mine is self learning curve hence it has got lots of down sides

Comment: I suggest, any time you find yourself using lots or loops (especially with arrays) and if statements, have a quick look at the php docs online and find alternatives. PHP comes with enough array and string functions that easily replace much of code out there. I suggest taking a good loop at the yahoo and google dev channels on youtube for good development practices. And look into design patterns, they're a must!

Comment: ok will do that...I have one more question for you...say I do have two sets of data $data1 = "mathew,luke,james,neil,ethan"; $data2 = "60%,68%,79%,92%,98%"; I want match both like mathew = 60% luke = 68% etc.. how can I do this without loops?? and many times total number of users and percentage will be vary

Comment: off the top of my head I'm pretty sure you can do without loops. Definitely if you're willing to change the array structure. Best to open a new question as code formatting isn't available in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using a counter `$i`, you could just perform the following check:

```
if ($i === count($data) - 2) {
    echo ' and ';
}
```

...or whatever. It doesn't have to be `echo`.

Comment: @leon I think `count` is one after the last, `-1` is the last one, and `-2` is second-to-last. In my fake PHP loop in my head, I was adding the `and` after the second-to-last, rather than before the last.

Comment: but how do I add this in above loop??

Comment: @leon I don't really think you can, the way you have it right now. It looks like you're adding the values to an array, and then just `echo`ing the array. Am I wrong?

Comment: oh I was thinking on same but it seems Gus idea can work but I need count it from begining. I want only first three results and after two I need to add AND. remember total data can be upto 12 or 14 it varies

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = explode(",", $str);
for ($i = 0; $i<count($data)-1; $i++) {
   $sentence = $sentence.$data[$i].", ";
}
$sentence = $sentence."and ".end($data).".";
echo $sentence;
```

What this will do is store all of the names except for the last one in a variable, with commas, and then at the end adds the last one with "and" before it.

That variable - $sentence - is then echoed (displayed).

EDIT:
To only display the first three results is simple.

```
$data = explode(",", $str);
echo $data[0].", ".$data[1].", and ".$data[2];
```

The $data[x] simply returns one of the names, which are stored in order.

Comment: Couldn't you just explode `$data`, edit the last one to include "and " before it, and then join with ", "?

Comment: I figured he wanted to use the code he had above as a foundation. But yeah, that would be a great way to do it.

Comment: how can I count from the begining? say I want only first three result then??